# ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: include

Tags: ssh, openssh

In my `~/.ssh/config` I added the following:

`Include /Path/to/ssh.config`

And it gives error:

```
ssh remoteEc-2
/Users/Me/.ssh/config: line 1: Bad configuration option: include
/Users/Me/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

`ssh -V` gives:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
```

I am on OSX El-Capitan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Include` is not a valid option until version 7.3...

See: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3

> ### New Features
>
> [...]
>
> - ssh(1): Add an Include directive for ssh_config(5) files.

Also, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/247564/is-there-a-way-for-one-ssh-config-file-to-include-another-one).

---

If you can't / don't want to update, then you could collate your configuration files, using the following:

```sh
cat ${CONFIG_1} ${CONFIG_2} ${CONFIG_3} > ~/.ssh/config
```

You'd need to run it every time you update any of the parts...

Comment: hm.. so I am using default OSX ssh.. a bit afraid to install and use homebrew version.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a method to 'collate' your configuration files...

Comment: There is only one configuration file that is part of a Github repo. I will update it based on changes. Is `${CONFIG_1}` a variable here?

Comment: If you only have one config, then you could look at using a symbolic link... either way, be careful of using an SSH config file from a repository, as it would be easy for others to modify it, and for you to miss the changes... yep, `${CONFIG_1}` is standard bash notation for a variable.

Answer (score 9):

Same problem, except I'm on 7.4

Turns out, [the `Include` directive needs to go into /etc/ssh/ssh_config](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/02/msg00096.html), not `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (note the `d` in the filename).

Wasn't obvious to me. Hope this saves whoever finds this some time.

Comment: Quick explanation on what's the difference. A Linux computer can act both as an SSH server accepting connections, as well an SSH client making connections. The `d` in `sshd_config` stands for daemon, which runs in the background waiting for external connections. While the regular `ssh_config` controls how your linux machine (even a server) connects to other computers (e.g. Git servers or backup hosts).